# change the list of combobox A based on the item chosen from combobox B

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb.net and I am using visual studio 2010. I have two comboboxes on a form, each combobox is set to DropDownList so that a list of items can show in the combobox, but no text is allowed to be entered.

For combobox A, if user chooses item 1, the list of combobox B should be updated accordingly. I think this is quite common on a lot of applications. But I do not know to implement it. I even do not know the keyword to search for the relevant property or event handler.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [SelectedValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged.aspx).  You can subscrive to this event on your first combobox, then when the event is raised, you can `combo2.Items.Clear ()` the 2nd collection, then add your items.